# Laravel Expected status code 200 but received 500

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, tdd

That's the code for my unit test, the default one:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

I'm running the laravel project on: `php artisan serv`

When I manually access the `/` the project works fine! however on the test I'm getting this error:

```
  Expected status code 200 but received 500.
  Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 500.
```

Here it is the full output:

```
  FAIL  Tests\Feature\ExampleTest
  ⨯ basic test

  ---

  • Tests\Feature\ExampleTest > basic test
  Expected status code 200 but received 500.
  Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 500.

  at tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php:19
     15▕     public function testBasicTest()
     16▕     {
     17▕         $response = $this->get('/');
     18▕ 
  ➜  19▕         $response->assertStatus(200);
     20▕     }
     21▕ }
     22▕
```

How can I fix that please?

Comment: Is there a stack trace displaying in the test run output? That should give you some information about the 500 error, such as file and line number.

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper i did put the full output

Comment: It seems like there is something wrong with your testing environment which is causing an error. There's likely some more information in the output of the test run, which would include something called a stack trace. That should contain some more information about the 500 error that was encountered and help point you towards what is going wrong. I would recommend spending some time learning about stack traces in php (a quick google search turns up a few nice looking blog posts on the topic) and seeing if that helps move you forward. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Before your `$this->get()` call, insert a call to `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()`. It will show you the detail of the error.

Comment: On my end session permission was denied.

Answer (score 0):

in my case:

i added env variable that forget to add to my .env.testing

by this comment: @jamesclark

```
It seems like there is something wrong with your testing environment which is causing an error
```

ican understand and add it to my .env file and all test run as well